# SQL Server 2014 SP3 Backup to URL error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup, azure-blob-storage

We have a database on a SQL Server 2014 (SP3 12.0.6433.1) and I'm trying to take a backup to Azure Blob Storage.

I have followed this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/2014/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2014) and created a credential using identity and access key using the following code:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL mycredential WITH IDENTITY = 'mystorageaccount'
,SECRET = '<storage access key>' ;
```

and tried to do a backup using the following code:

```
BACKUP DATABASE mydb
TO URL = 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydb.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'mycredential'
,COMPRESSION
,STATS = 5;
GO
```

[However, I am getting the following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poyXP.png)

```
Msg 3271, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydb.bak:" Backup to URL received an exception from the remote endpoint. Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel..
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The database is ~3GB. The error is thrown after the query executes for about 1.5 mins.

The Azure storage account I am using is a General Purpose V1 Storage account. However, I have also tried this with a V2 account.

Has anyone gone through this?

Comment: Possibly TLS versioning issue? Try monitoring the connection with Wireshark and see what TLS version is negotiated. Are you running the latest build of SQL Server 2014?

Comment: @Charlieface, yep seems to be a TLS 1.2 issue. Since we don't have TLS 1.1/1.0 enabled on the source server, the communication seems to be failing. Not sure why since we are using SQL server 2014 SP3. 
Anyway, we went ahead with the backup to disk workaround. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: TLS1.2 depends on SChannel support for it in the operating system, so if it doesn't have it then SQL Server won't either.

Comment: +1 on the TLS version. Just had the same issue last week and it was caused by the TLS version. Reverted back to 1.0 and it worked like a charm. I would also check the exact version - support for TLS 1.2 was added in SP3, so installing that might also fix your issue.